# SecurityTest issue when loading a Worklight 5.0.3 project in Worklight 5.0.6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, authenticity

I have imported a worklight 5.0.3 project in worklight 5.0.6.
When deploying the wlapps on the worklight console ( studio test environment ), I have the App. Authentication set to Disabled. It was not under version 5.0.3

Is there any change between the two versions concerning the authenticationConfig.xml file ?

Comment: Which environment? Does the environment have a securityTest defined for it? What is it? What does it contain (if it is a custom one, look in authenticationConfig.xml and edit your post with it).

Answer (score 0):

App Authentication refers to the Authenticity feature. Unless you have Authenticity properly enabled in authenticationConfig.xml as well as the securityTest set for the supported environments (in application-descriptor.xml), this feature will appear greyed out.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding a <TestAppAuthenticity/> in the concerned securityTest in the file authenticationConfig.xml. Is it what you mean by "Authenticity properly enabled in authenticationConfig.xml " ?